# changing the image size according to the value of the select box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drupal

I have a select box which has options like width X height format. While selecting a width and height, I have to make the below image(in the div 'other') in to that size.
I tried the below code:

```
<script src="http://test/sites/js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.target').change(function() {
            $value=document.getElementById('target').value;
            var myArray = $value.split('X'); 
            document.getElementById('other').innerHTML = '<img src="http://test/sites/all/themes/artsy/images/images2.jpeg" width="myArray[0]" height="myArray[1]">';
        });
    });
</script>
<form>
    <select class="target" id="target">
        <option value="20 X 30" selected="selected">20 X 30</option>
        <option value="100 X 150">100 X 150</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="other"> 
    <?php echo $value; ?> <img src="http://test/sites/all/themes/artsy/images/images2.jpeg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have modify your javascript code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('.target').change(function() {
  $value=document.getElementById('target').value;
var myArray = $value.split('X'); 
document.getElementById('other').innerHTML = '
<img src="http://test/sites/all/themes/artsy/images/images2.jpeg" width="'+myArray[0]+'px" height="'+myArray[1]+'px ">';


});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks good. No problems to speak of, other than the fact that you're not declaring any pixels and you're referencing the javascript variables improperly. You need to change the width and height properties to something like this ->

```
width="'+myArray[0]+'px" 
height="'+myArray[1]+'px"
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your existing code a bit, try this with jQuery's ".attr"  function:

```
    $('.target').change(function() {
    $value=document.getElementById('target').value;
    var myArray = $value.split('X');
    $('#other').attr("width",myArray[0]);
    $('#other').attr("height",myArray[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.target').change(function() {
        var pVal = $('#target').val();
        var myArray = pVal.split(' X '); // Note the extra spacing.
        $('#other').html('<img src="http://test/sites/all/themes/artsy/images/images2.jpeg" width="'+myArray[0]+'" height="'+myArray[0]+'">');
    });
});
</script>

Of course, you'll find it easier to do the actual update like this:
    $('#other img').attr('width',myArray[0]).attr('height',myArray[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<select name="something" id="resoultion">
  <option value="100_200">100 X 200</option>
  <option value="200_400">200 X 400</option>
  <option value="300_600">300 X 600</option>
</select>
<img src="img.jpg" id="imageID" alt="" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#resoultion').change(function() {
 var resolution = $(this).val().split('_');
 var width = resolution[0];
 var height = resolution[1];

 $('#imageID').css({
  width: width,
  height: height
 });
});
```